# "If the code is in an Astro component, move it to a <script> tag outside of the frontmatter."

Tags: javascript, typescript, astrojs

I am trying to import JS for navigation into my Astro project. The error I get is "Browser APIs are not available on the server.

If the code is in a framework component, try to access these objects after rendering using lifecycle methods or use a client:only directive to make the component exclusively run on the client.

See https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/troubleshooting/#document-or-window-is-not-defined for more information."

The script does use both window and document. However I am unsure how to import the script outside the frontmatter.

Thanks a lot.

I have tried importing the script and am using:

---

### import '../js/menu.js';

inside Header.astro.

However I cannot figure out how to import it outside of the frontmatter.

I have also tried using "is:inline". The error messages are removed but the JS does not work.

Thanks